# IE dynamic DOM events not triggering

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, eventtrigger

Using oninput and onblur attributes. The content is loaded with ajax (elements do not exist before).

IE ver: 11.1480.14393.0

The problem does not exist in IE ver 11.0.9600.18793

**This is not triggering**

```
<input type="text" oninput="dosomething(1);" />
```

After i change it in developer view, it starts working. It does not work however, when i edit it but make no changes to it. Example:

```
<input type="text" oninput="dosomething(2);" />
```

It seems as if IE does not register elements that are loaded dynamically, unless you add/edit them by dev-view.

**Also tried:** Added element to page by console with oninput attribute. "Broken IE" did not trigger, worked in other browsers.

**EDIT 1:**

Adding some proof:

[IE and OS versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNXUE.png)

[Gif of the whole shabang (not)happening and then working after change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Br8J.gif)

Comment: This is extremely hard to believe. Much more likely something *else* is going on, that you've made some other change, than that Microsoft massively broke IE between 11.0 and 11.1480.  Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Comment: I'm curious where you got "IE ver: 11.1480.14393.0". I have a fully-updated Windows 8.1 VM, and it only has v11.0.9600.18817. Surely you're not using IE on Windows 10?

Comment: Edited with some info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the events were not even attached to the elements and thus there was nothing to trigger. Cause: **javascript was not enabled** because of the security level.

1. **Options** on the browser menu bar.
2. Click the **Security tab**.
3. Click the **Internet icon**.
4. Click **Custom Level**.
5. Click the **Scripting > Active Scripting** list item.
6. Click **Enable**.
7. Refesh page / **restart IE**

Source: [enable javascript in windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135465/how-to-enable-javascript-in-windows)